# How far did the MUSTARD project get?

Tags: launch-vehicle, engineering

http://www.astronautix.com/m/mustard.html
As described above, MUSTARD was a BAC project to develop a fully reusable VTO/HL shuttle to transport crew and payload to earth orbit.
There were many iterations, ending at about #12, but I don't have a reference for that.
I want to understand more about what stage this project got to, as articles and papers are few and far in-between.
(Basically did it get to: paper/scale models/prototype/etc., as well as more information on the project in general.)

[image]
Image source: [The Grimsby man who invented the space shuttle](https://www.grimsbytelegraph.co.uk/news/nostalgia/space-shuttle-mustard-tom-smith-1779305)

Comment: I rather like that one myself.

Comment: Looks like we need to turn up a copy of this book, but I haven't found one for sale at any price :( https://www.abebooks.com/9781910809020/British-Secret-Projects-Britains-Space-1910809020/plp

Comment: MUSTARD went pretty far, but then it fell behind schedule and could't catchup.

Comment: Looks like only paper. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAC_Mustard - no mention of hardware or technology maturation.

Comment: Colonel Mustard only made it to the library with the candlestick...

Comment: @OrganicMarble I actually found this one at my library, but the details were limited, from memory.

Comment: I've requested the book from Interlibrary Loan, but sometimes that takes a long time.

Answer (score 3):

The [BAC MUSTARD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BAC_Mustard) was a groundbreaking project that died when the British government lost interest. According to the 2016 book you mention in the comments ("[British secret projects. 5, Britain's space shuttle](https://archive.org/details/britishsecretpro0000shar/mode/1up)" by Dan Sharp, *available by the hour* at the Internet Archive), there were 16 MUSTARD (Multi-Unity Space Transport And Recovery Device) iterations. Scheme #14 was being worked on when the program's government funding ran out in 1965, but [British Aerospace Corporation (BAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aircraft_Corporation) continued on its own money,  completing scheme 15 and finishing with a "final" scheme. The programme's ultimate end came when it was clear the government was never going to provide more money.

There appears to have been only designs on paper and some small wind-tunnel models. The programme was notable for its emphasis on ["Economical Space Transportation"](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0001924000056724) and early use of computer simulations as part of the design process.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the Internet Archive version of the book! Great answer too.